# Rails Strong parameters Nested ressources Child and Outside

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, nested, strong-parameters

I have nested resources like that :

```
resources :cards do
    resources :teammates
    resources :formata, only: [:index, :show]
end
```

- I use formata#show to render an alternative card#show
- Cards has_many teammates

QUESTION : I would like to display all the infos available inside Cards table (city, place, ...), and the infos of the Teammates belonging to the card (firstname, lastname) => in the formata#show view.

I do not know how to set the strong parameters to work well.

For the moment I have in formata controller :

```
class FormataController < ApplicationController
 before_filter :authenticate_crafter!
 before_action :set_card, only: [:show]

 def index
  render ("formata/show")
 end

 def show
  @card = Card.find(params[:card_id])
  @teammates = Teammates.where(card_id: @card).take!
 end

 private
  def set_card
   @card = Card.find(params[:card_id])
  end

 def formata_params
  params.require(:card).permit(:content, :city, :place)
 end
end
```

Triggered with url like this :

```
http://www.appname.com/cards/:id_card/formata
```

And my view formata/show.html.erb contains:

```
City <%= @Card.city %>
Place <%= @Card.place %>
```

Rendering view error:

```
undefined method `city' for nil:NilClass
```

None of my 2 variables @card & @teammates work in formata#show. And work well in #teammates (same level of nest).

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: can you please paste the params you are receiving in show action from the server logs.

Comment: Sure, Parameters: {"card_id"=>"47"}

Comment: though i am sure that my answer help you but i would also like to know is there any relation defined in model between Card and teammates

Comment: inside model i have card has_many teammates, and teammates belong_to cards
However I didn't set formata model.

Comment: it should be belongs_to :card not cards also @card.teammates is equal to Teammates.where(card_id: @card)

Answer (score 1):

it is case sensitive. card should be in small case as it is coming from controler

```
<%= @Card.city %>
```

change it to

```
<%= @card.city %>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it was a typo on stackoverflow, It is already @card inside view :/ My bad

Comment: one more thing why are you doing this twice @card = Card.find(params[:card_id]) one in show and second through set_card

Comment: No reason about redundacy of card = Card.find(params[:card_id]), just have the habit to precise it in each action, and delete it at the end.

On interesting thing is that without "render" in index action, and copy-past of my formata#show view inside my formata#index view, card is loaded proprely and displays info. Teammates not.

So I guess there is a problem with my teammates request in controller and a problem in passign parameters card and teammates with the render.

Comment: Here is my formata#show view as requested:

Test show view
<%= @card.place %>